# Swift4 - Как в написанном цикле исключить пробел перед 1 символом

Tags: swift4

Есть условие:

```
let fullName = "EvgeniyVladimirovich"
```

Нужно написать код, при введении слитно имени, отчества и фамилии, то он ставил бы пробел между заглавными:

```
var newName = String()
        for character in fullName {
            if String(character) == String(character).uppercased() {
                newName.append(" ")
            }
            newName.append(String(character))
        }

        print(fullName)
```

Данный код работает, но как мне исключить установку пробела перед первым заглавным символом E?

Answer (score 0):

Если с минимальными правками - добавьте в Ваш вариант проверку индекса:

```
var newName = String()
for (index, character) in fullName.enumerated() {
    if String(character) == String(character).uppercased() && index != 0 {
        newName.append(" ")
    }
    newName.append(String(character))
}
print(newName)
```

Comment: Хорошая идея, спасибо.